# class friendship & Protection and Accessibility Levels in C#

Tags: c#, levels

I'm looking for one special access level like friendship in c# for one member of my class M that I cannot find here :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx

### Question 1:

Assume I have a secret value like password in my class M, that I don't want any object to have access to it, but for some reasons I want only other instance of class M can read and use this value like:
m1.similarity(m2)  ==> calculate similarity between  m1.password and m2.password

### Question 2:

If there is no way to implement the previous example, is it possible to define a friend class like below :
anotherclass.similarity(m1,m2)

p.s: This is just an example to make the question clear and I know about possible security impact of method similarity()

Comment: In general, regarding security: access modifiers are not meant to enforce security. Practically anything can be retrieved using reflection in c#.

Comment: I think you have a design issue if you really need to resolve your problem this way.

Comment: 1) IF both sides are the same class, you can simply use `private`. 2) For security you need special annotations and obviously it doesn't protect against fully trusted code.

Comment: Well as I explained in the last part it is just an example. I know it is a kind of an exceptional behavior but I think it is much better to make the password private and add an exceptional friend class that do the job for me rather than making password public and let careless developer make stupid mistakes.

Comment: Again, the purpose of making password private is not security reasons but I don't want careless developer to mistakenly use it when press DOT button.  ;)

Comment: Problem solved. I really don't think I have any problem in my design @BobHorn . take a look at my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks every one, I finally solved the problem with a helper method like this :

```
int Similiarity (M other)
{
return other.SimiliarityHelper(this.password)
}


int SimiliarityHelper (string otherpass){
return compareString(this.password, otherpass)
}
```

Comment: where is the advantage over `compareString(password, other.password)`?